# IF statement containing two isset()

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

Here is my code:

```
if( ( ! isset($_GET['year']) ) || ( ! isset($_GET['make']) ) || $_GET['make'] == 0 ) {
    echo 0;
    exit;
}
```

It keeps returning 0... when year and make are set and make does not equal 0...

This is the URL I'm passing through:

> http://mopar.localhost/ajax/populateVehicle.php?column=model&year=2014&make=Chrysler

Why does this keep returning 0? Even if I delete the `$_GET['make'] == 0`, it still comes back as 0.. can you not have two isset() conditions?

Comment: What's the problem? year is set (so the first condition is false). make is set (the second is false), and make is not equal to 0 (the third is false too). So false

Comment: No it's saying if year is not set, return false. But year is set, so it's not going to go into that if statement execution.. look at the "!"

Comment: just one true will execute the code, may be the 2nd and 3rd conditions are logically duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like PHP is treating a string compared to an integer as true (`$_GET["make"] == 0`).

The reason for this is `$_GET["make"]` is being implicitly cast as an int for the comparison.  When you try to convert a string to an int, on failure the value 0 is returned.

Compare `$_GET['make']` to the string "0" instead.

```
if ( 
        ( ! isset( $_GET['year'] ) ) || 
        ( ! isset( $_GET['make'] ) ) || 
        $_GET['make'] == "0"
    ) {
    echo 0;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. You said `Even if I delete the $_GET['make'] == 0, it still comes back as 0`, which indicates that this wasn't the (only) problem. What happened with that?

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew, `$_GET['make'] === 0` will be never identical, all values from **_POST**, **_GET** was treated as string, you've to do the cast if you want to change its type.

P.S: i can't comment because doesn't have reputation for it. 
Sorry.

Comment: That is a really good point.  I understand why PHP was doing that too.  It implicity cast `$_GET["make"]` to an int, because it was being compared to an int.  When a string fails to convert to an int, the value 0 is returned.

Comment: PHP itself doesn't cast to integer because you're comparing to, you have to do it.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting Check this out.  The first line says that `a value will be automatically converted if an operator, function or control structure requires an integer argument`

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't occurs in _GET, _POST try by yourself.
http://ideone.com/QrX279 `bool(false)`.

:P

Comment: And as far i know, the casting of type `a` only occurs if you'd `'0' == 0`, doesn't make sense a language have support for an "identical" operator if he does the cast to the same type for you, kay ?

Comment: I modified your example to the match the question and explanation.  http://ideone.com/kosU0R.  The reason why he can't use the identical operator is because it doesn't convert.  So this is true: `'0' !== 0`. Unfortunately, if you explicitly cast a string that isn't a valid number, you get 0.  so `intval( $_GET["make"] ) === 0` will ALWAYS return true if `$_GET["make"]` is a string.

Comment: Yes, that's okay, but he aren't casting, when you have answered, you didn't do the cast to properly type, btw, i think he should use: `(int) $_GET['make'] == 0`, only.

Comment: That's why I changed my question based on your point (I also said it was a good point) :)  I removed the reference to the identical operator, that isn't the correct way for him to go.  We can't play with casting here with the logic he needs, because the failed response is `0`.